# How do I calculate the resource requirements for using Solr?

Tags: 6, search

I want to use Apache Solr for faceted navigation of my D6 site(s), but I'm unsure of the resource requirements for it. How do I check if my VPS can cope with implementing it?

Comment: I think you might get a better answer by being much much more specific. How big / what kind of server is it. How many indexes will you have, how big will they be? How much traffic will you expect? What else is running on the VPS?

Comment: Hi - well, the VPS has four virtual cores (no idea what speed or any other tech specs), 1Gb RAM, 512Mb burstable, 100Gb disk space. I don't expect more than 50 visitors per day at the moment. The server runs mail and web at the moment. It doesn't get a lot of traffic by any stretch of the imagination. I have no idea how many indexes I will have, nor how big they will be - I don't even know what they are. Hence, trying to find out how I go about seeing how the server would cope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the most complete answer but no one else has stepped up so hopefully this can be somewhat helpful.

I would say that the biggest potential issues on a box that size would be running out of memory and disk space. You can [allocate memory to your java vm](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors#Memory_allocated_to_the_Java_VM) to mitigate potential memory issues. Solr is under load when indexing and retrieving search results (obviously). You can mitigate the indexing load by indexing in small batches. Though in terms of memory footprint if you are substituting solr with normal Drupal search your load on apache/mysql will be greatly reduced.

I would say that I've run multiple solr instances with a higher load than you are describing on a 1GB VPS.

You may get a more detailed answer if you go to ServerFault or the [Solr mailing list](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/discussion.html) and share the solrconfig.xml and schema.xml files from the ApacheSolr module.

Comment: Hi acouch, thanks for your reply. It's certainly a step forward in terms of the info I'm looking for. I'll try experimenting with the memory allocation for Java VM and see how Solr copes with that. From what you're saying, it might not cause too many issues in my circumstances, if you've run higher loads on 1Gb. Thanks :)